# SetMargin on Cell not working in itext7 .NET library

Tags: itext, itext7

I am attempting to recreate the CellMarginPadding example found here using C#:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-5#2035-c05e05_cellmarginpadding.java

Everything works as expected *EXCEPT the margins*. There are no margins at all set on the cells on which SetMargin(), SetMarginBottom(), or SetMarginTop() is called.

My C# code is a direct port as seen below:

```
        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

        Table table = new Table(new float[] {2, 1, 1});
        table.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE);
        table.SetWidthPercent(80);
        table.SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        table.AddCell(new Cell(1, 3).Add("Cell with colspan 3")
            .SetPadding(10).SetMargin(5).SetBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN));

        table.AddCell(new Cell(2, 1).Add("Cell with rowspan 2")
            .SetMarginTop(5).SetMarginBottom(5).SetPaddingLeft(30)
            .SetFontColor(Color.WHITE).SetBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE));

        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add("row 1; cell 1")
            .SetFontColor(Color.WHITE).SetBackgroundColor(Color.RED));

        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add("row 1; cell 2"));

        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add("row 2; cell 1").SetMargin(10)
            .SetFontColor(Color.WHITE).SetBackgroundColor(Color.RED));

        table.AddCell(new Cell().Add("row 2; cell 2").SetPadding(10)
            .SetFontColor(Color.WHITE).SetBackgroundColor(Color.RED));

        document.Add(table);

        document.Close();
```

Am I doing this wrong? Or is it possible there is a bug in the itext7 .NET library?

Comment: I have an update for you. Actually, your question was very interesting. Because of your question, I found out that the tutorial that was supposed to be reviewed, wasn't reviewed thoroughly enough. I will now review it myself.

Comment: Actually, I have converted all of the tutorial samples to C# at https://github.com/LeeDumond/iTextBuildingBlocks if you are interested.

Comment: While you are reviewing, you might note that several of the Chapter 5 tutorials still use obsoleted methods for table instantiation...

Comment: Wow, you did a great job. I have asked someone at iText to contact you, and make those examples more official, e.g. by adding them to the official site with the proper acknowledgments and a link back to your site. And yes, the examples in our git repository were updated to the latest version, including the cmp ("compare") files (because all the examples are also tests), but I didn't know the person who updated the examples didn't update the examples on the site and in the tutorial. I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want the reintroduction of a bug that existed in iText 7.0.0.

I have converted your code sample to HTML:

```
<table style="background: orange; text-align: center; width: 80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="padding: 10pt; margin: 5pt; background: green;">Cell with colspan 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="color: white; background: blue; margin-top: 5pt; margin-bottom: 30pt; padding-left: 30pt">Cell with rowspan 2</td>
    <td style="color: white; background: red">row 1; cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1; cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="color: white; background: red; margin: 10pt;">row 2; cell 1</td>
    <td style="color: white; background: red; padding: 10pt;">row 2; cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I converted the values for the margins, paddings, colors,... in your C# code to inline CSS values in the HTML. Then I converted that HTML to PDF.

You can see the HTML and the PDF in the following screen shot:

[image]

Wouldn't you agree that the PDF looks as expected?

If you want us to look into this matter, please provide some HTML code that creates a table that shows exactly what it is that you want to achieve when you define a margin. It would be interesting for us to check if pdfHTML converts that HTML to PDF that looks more or less identical. If it does, and if you really want to code your table, you can then use the code that is used by pdfHTML (an add-on on top of iText 7) to mimic the same result straight from code.

**Update:**

Because of your question, I have started updating chapter 5 of the Building Blocks tutorial. I still have plenty of work to do, but I can already tell you what I discovered.

As I already mentioned in my initial answer, margins are ignored in `Cell` objects because CSS margins are ignored in HTML table cells. The iText 7 `CellRenderer` code was changed in function of the pdfHTML add-on:

```
@Override
protected Rectangle applyMargins(Rectangle rect, float[] margins, boolean reverse) {
    // Do nothing here. Margins shouldn't be processed on cells.
    return rect;
}
```

Of course, if you want to get the original behavior, you can override the `CellRenderer`. That's what I did in the [CellMarginPadding2](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I7JS/repos/highlevel/browse/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/highlevel/chapter05/C05E05_CellMarginPadding2.java) example:

```
private class MarginCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    public MarginCellRenderer(Cell modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    protected Rectangle applyMargins(Rectangle rect, float[] margins, boolean reverse) {
        return rect.<Rectangle>applyMargins(margins[0], margins[1], margins[2], margins[3], reverse);
    }
}

private class MarginCell extends Cell {
    public MarginCell() {
        super();
    }

    public MarginCell(int rowspan, int colspan) {
        super(rowspan, colspan);
    }

    @Override
    protected IRenderer makeNewRenderer() {
        return new MarginCellRenderer(this);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new C05E05_CellMarginPadding2().createPdf(DEST);
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    //Initialize PDF document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

    // Initialize document
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{2, 1, 1}));
    table.setBackgroundColor(Color.ORANGE);
    table.setWidthPercent(80);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    table.addCell(
        new MarginCell(1, 3).add("Cell with colspan 3")
            .setPadding(10).setMargin(5).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN));
    table.addCell(new MarginCell(2, 1).add("Cell with rowspan 2")
        .setMarginTop(5).setMarginBottom(5).setPaddingLeft(30)
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE));
    table.addCell(new MarginCell().add("row 1; cell 1")
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));
    table.addCell(new MarginCell().add("row 1; cell 2"));
    table.addCell(new MarginCell().add("row 2; cell 1").setMargin(10)
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));
    table.addCell(new MarginCell().add("row 2; cell 2").setPadding(10)
        .setFontColor(Color.WHITE).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED));
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

I created a `MarginCell` class that renders cells using the `MarginCellRenderer`. In that renderer, I override the `applyMargins()` method, so that the margins are no longer ignored.

This fixes your problem. Changes to chapter 5 of the tutorial will be applied as soon as possible (depending on how many people demand my time on Stack Overflow :D ).

Comment: OK, I was going nuts because the result I was getting did not match the screenshot in your tutorial I got the code from (I converted it straight over from the original Java).

Comment: I see why you changed the behavior though. I actually agree with your design decision here, makes perfect sense actually.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial for this on the iText website.

Check out https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-alignment-indentation-leading-and-spacing-cells
for a code sample.

```
protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    PdfCanvas cb = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
    cb.moveTo(36, 842);
    cb.lineTo(36, 0);
    cb.stroke();
    Table table = new Table(8);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    table.setWidth(150);
    for (int aw = 0; aw < 16; aw++) {
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("hi")));
    }
    table.setMarginLeft(25);
    doc.add(table);

    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, I don't need a sample. I understand HOW the library works. I am simply pointing out that setting margins on table cells is not working with the .NET version, and was hoping either a) perhaps someone else could reproduce this behavior, or b) tell me specifically what I am doing wrong, if anything.

Comment: I assumed you would benefit from a code-sample. Since the entire code-base is thoroughly tested via both integration and unit-tests. And we'd know if margins were suddenly behaving strangely.

Comment: I have tested the code, and I see that there's a difference between the screen-shot in the tutorial, and what I get as result today. The tutorial was written before iText 7 was officially released. I think the behavior has changed in more recent versions. I created an HTML file using the same `margin` and `padding` values in CSS as in the C# example. The HTML looks like the PDF I get today. I think that the behavior expected by @MissingLinq is the result of a bug that was fixed. The tutorial should be rewritten to reflect the current version of iText.

Comment: Note that I got a better result (not perfect yet though) when replacing `setMargin(10)` by `SetBorderLeft(new SolidBorder(Color.BLACK, 10, 0))`.